# Changing childs layout params have a wierd effect on its parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

So I have a layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/rl_tooltip"
    android:visibility="gone"
    tools:visibility="visible">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v_triangle"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tooltip_triangle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/v_triangle"
        android:background="@drawable/tooltip_bg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/color_fefefe"
        tools:text="New Tooltip text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

which I am inflating like this

```
 View content = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_tooltip, viewGroup, false);
        View v = viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.rl_tooltip);
```

So here is the thing when I am adding this content view to parent layout its working fine with layout width wrap_content which after being calculated is around 400px but when I am changing the layoutparams of the child view v_triangle

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams marginLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            marginLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            contentView.findViewById(R.id.v_triangle).setLayoutParams(marginLayoutParams);
```

like this, the layouts width is now 1080px (i.e. screen width).

So I don't understand why the layout's behaviour is changing. I need that view's actual width.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
    View triangle = contentView.findViewById(R.id.v_triangle);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams marginLayoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) triangle.getLayoutParams();
    marginLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    triangle.setLayoutParams(marginLayoutParams);
```

The problem is that your `v_triangle` view doesn't have anything to define its width/height (`android:background` doesn't define intrinsic dimensions), so when you write

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams marginLayoutParams = 
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

you're actually going to wind up with a view that is as large as it can be. Rather than creating a new `LayoutParams` object, simply re-use the existing one by calling `View.getLayoutParams()`. Note that you still have to re-assign the params with `View.setLayoutParams()` for the changes to actually take effect.

Comment: But when I am using RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout as parent of the triangle same thing happens.